# Rendering Objects with dynamic data in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rendering

I am currently working on a OpenGL Renderer in C++. I have created a base *Object* class that looks a bit like this:

```cpp
class Object
{
...
private:
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<uint16_t> indices;
};
```

*Vertex* is a simple struct containing the data of a vertex.

```cpp
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 location;
    glm::vec4 color;
};
```

Anything being rendered is considered an *Object*. The vertex data of each Object needs to change every frame, so my vertex buffer allocates a certain amount of memory on startup and the vertex data of all Objects is uploaded to the GPU each frame using glBufferSubData. I then have a *Scene* class which stores a vector of all the existing *Objects*. The Renderer merges the vertex data of each object every frame like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Vertex> all_vertices;
std::vector<uint16_t> all_indices;

for (const Object* object : objects)
{
    all_vertices.insert(all_vertices.end(), std::make_move_iterator(object->get_vertices_begin()), std::make_move_iterator(object->get_vertices_end()));
    all_indices.insert(all_indices.end(), std::make_move_iterator(object->get_indices_begin()), std::make_move_iterator(object->get_indices_end()));
}

draw(vertices, indices);
```

My concern here is the performance of these operations, especially all the heap allocations by std::vector. The Renderer can't know how many total vertices and indices there are, since this could change any frame

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::vector::reserve` to reserve the same amount of space that you have determined the GPU will need. Then use `std::vector::clear` in each frame before you start pushing things in.

This way you only allocate from the heap once, as long as you don't push more than you reserved.

It's worth noting that you can override the `std` allocator and provide your own one if you want to take control of `std` container allocations. But that's another topic for another question. As is whether you should even use `std` containers.

Top tip: measure performance before and after making optimisation changes to check that your assumptions are correct.